# Postgres INSERT ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING vs SELECT + INSERT query

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, upsert

I have table `stock_price_code` as below. `value` column has a `UNIQUE` constraint.

```
create table stock_price_code (
    id serial primary key,
    value text not null,
    unique (value)
);
```

I want to `INSERT` into table, if no record found for `value`. I have these 2 queries:

```
-- query 1
INSERT INTO stock_price_code (value)
    SELECT 'MCD'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stock_price_code WHERE value = 'MCD')
    RETURNING id;


-- query 2
INSERT INTO stock_price_code (value) VALUES ('MCD')
    ON CONFLICT (value) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id;
```

I was using `query 1` before Postgres 9.5. Then Postgres 9.5 started introducing `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` feature. If I substitude `query 1` with `query 2`, is there any known side effect or perfomance issue? Thanks.

Comment: `insert on conflict` is safe for concurrent transactions while the other query is not. If there is a side effect, then that the new code will work more reliably - you don't need to check for a unique key violation any more

Comment: Noted on the concurrent transaction thing. However, after some experiment, I decided to stick to `query 2` for my use case. I explain why in the comment for answer below. Appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*query 2* will work if a row gets inserted between `SELECT 'MCD'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM stock_price_code WHERE value = 'MCD')` and `INSERT INTO stock_price_code (value)`, while *query 1* will fail with duplicate.

The overhead of `ON CONFLICT` I believe is smaller then `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, not sure though

Comment: I just realize with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`, there is 1 drawback where the auto increment `SERIAL` get incremented each time, no matter there is `INSERT` or not. Although there is no big deal with gaps in `SERIAL`, but this query is run very often & most of the time it ends up `DO NOTHING`. To avoid this, I think I will stick to `query 1` for my use case. Thanks for your explanation, appreciate that!